# Data conversion using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the module dataformat to get a data from a timestamp but I get an error and I can't understand why.

that's the timestamp `1405303200` and I need the Date in this format `dd/mm/yyyy`

That's my code

> var day=dateFormat(result.request_date, "dd/mm/yyyy");

But what I get is the `1970-01-17` date asd.

Comment: timestamp is incorrect

Comment: it comes from the openWeather API http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=35&lon=139&cnt=10&mode=json

Comment: yes multiply it with 1000

Comment: new Date(1405303200 * 1000).toLocaleString().split(" ")[0]

Comment: thank you so much now I understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using a timestamp saved by PHP... now convert it to miliseconds

```
var timestamp = 1405303200  *1000;
```